# How to create a menu within a menu (python 3 IDE PyCharm)

Tags: python-3.x, menu

Hi I am new to Python and coding in general and would like to create a menu system. ideally if possible i would like there to be two options and then within the system another menu to select from. ive had a look and play about but cant seem to find anything/get it to work

the below is where im at, i cant seem to get the second menu to print and become a option.

```
def menu():
    print("[1]Laptops")
    print("[2]iPhones")
menu()

option = input("Choose your device")

if option == 1:
    print("[1]S5750")
    print("[2]S5577")
    print("[3]S5563")
    print("[4]S5744")
    print("[5]S5765")
    print("[6]S5944")
    print("[7]S5507")
    print("[8]S5509")

menu()
option = int(input("Choose your asset"))
```